# two for_each in terraform resource module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am new to tf. Trying to use two for_each in a resource module

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "event_rule" {
  name                = "${local.service_name}-trigger"
  description         = "Schedule for synthetic tests lambda function"
  for_each = var.cron_schedule
    schedule_expression = each.value.cron_schedule
  for_each = var.enable_event_schedule_trigger
    is_enabled = each.value.enable_event_schedule_trigger
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_lambda" {
 target_id = "${local.service_name}"
 arn       = aws_lambda_function.synthetictests.arn
 rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule.name
}
```

but getting following error.

```
The argument "for_each" was already set at lambda_trigers.tf:4,3-11. Each
argument may be set only once.
```

Variables

```
variable "cron_schedule" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "Cron schedule of lambda trigger via event bridge"
  default     = []
}

variable "enable_event_schedule_trigger" {
  type    = list(bool)
  default = ["false"]
  description = "flag to enable or disable event trigger. Disabled by 
  default"
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you provide example of `var.cron_schedule` and ` var.enable_event_schedule_trigger` variables?

Comment: updated the query.

Comment: I mean with some actual values, not empty lists.

Comment: cron_schedule = ["cron(30 19 ? * MON,THU *)","cron(30 10 ? * WED,SAT *)"]
enable_event_schedule_trigger = [true,true]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [zipmap](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/zipmap.html):

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "schedule_rule" {
  name                = "${local.service_name}-trigger"
  description         = "Schedule for synthetic tests lambda function"

  for_each            = zipmap(var.cron_schedule, var.enable_event_schedule_trigger)

  schedule_expression = each.key
  is_enabled          = each.value

}
```

**Update**

Since `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` uses, `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` should probably also use it:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_lambda" {

 for_each = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule

 target_id = "${local.service_name}"
 arn       = aws_lambda_function.synthetictests.arn
 rule      = each.value.name
}
```

Comment: Getting below errors with other resource modules
     `Error: Missing resource instance key
      on lambda_trigers.tf line 12, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "target_lambda":
     12:   rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule.name

     Because aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule has "for_each" set, its
     attributes must be accessed on specific instances.

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
      aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule[each.key]`

Comment: @SrikanthYadake Your quesiton does not have any `aws_cloudwatch_event_target`. This seems to be a new issue, thus new question should be asked.

Comment: yes, the error was thrown by a subsequent resource block, as the resource event_rule block used for_each.

Comment: @SrikanthYadake I don't know which block. Your question does not show any of its code.

Comment: edited the question, with the following module, please suggest.

Comment: @SrikanthYadake If you add for_each or count to one resource, it cascades to everything else. You may need to amend your entire codebase.

Comment: sure, can you please suggest on this line
 `rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule.name`
 
 I tried to change it to, but didnt work
`rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.event_rule[each.key]`

Comment: @SrikanthYadake I updated the answer, but if you have further issues, new question should be asked.